# Unique syncronization object to wait N threads completion

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I have a Threadpool class and this class has a wait() method. Now, the class can create N threads, and
when a thread is created, its handle is inserted in a container
The classic method I have used to implement the wait() function, is to traverse the container and wait
a single handle, like this:

```
thread_handle_iterator th = get_first_thread_handle_iterator();
thread_handle_iterator th2 = get_last_thread_handle_iterator();

while (th != th2)
{
     joint(*th);
     ++th;
}
```

And this works perfectly. Now, instead of having this loop, I could have an atomic counter
incremented when every thread starts running, and then decremented when the thread finished
to run. When the count==0 [the last thread is finishing] an event [or condition variable in posix] is fired.
Like this:

```
int
thread_entrypoint(Threadpool * p)
{
    int result;
    p->atomic_thread_count.add();
    result = p->getRunnable()->run();  // execute the thread code.
    if (p->atomic_thread_count.fetchAndAdd(-1) == 1) // this is the last thread!
    {
           p->event.signal(); // fires the event/condition variable
    }
    return result; // the thread returns the result and exits.
}
```

So, basically in this way I won't have an annoying container and I can detach all threads when I create
them: this will simplify very much my code. Then, even if the threads of the Threadpool are detached,
I still can wait on their completion, simply by calling `Threapool::wait() { event.wait(); }`

Plus, I have the advantage that I can add a global atomic counter, so i could wait on *every* threads
created by *every* Threadpool instances, like this:

```
AtomicInt global_threads_count;
WaitEvent global_all_threads_exited_event;

int
thread_entrypoint(Threadpool * p)
{
    int result;
    p->atomic_thread_count.add();
    global_threads_count.add();

    result = p->getRunnable()->run();  // execute the thread code.
    if (p->atomic_thread_count.fetchAndAdd(-1) == 1) // this is the last thread!
    {
           p->event.signal(); // fires the event/condition variable
    }

    if (global_threads_count.fetchAndAdd(-1) == 1) // this is the last thread of *ALL* threads!
    {
           global_all_threads_exited_event.signal(); // fires the event/condition variable
    }
    return result; // the thread returns the result and exits.
}
```

I can wait on *ALL* threads completion simply by calling `Threapool::waitForAllThreads() { global_all_threads_exited_event.wait(); }`

--
Would this be a reliable, fast, and effective design?

Comment: you are basically reimplementing the semaphore semantics.

Comment: Well, yes I know, would you just use a semaphore for that? I just thought that using atomic integers+event/cond.var. would be in someway "faster" than a semaphore..btw yes, its the same concept! My original question was if I can use this mechanism (or even a semaphore as you suggested) instead of loop and wait(handle); for each thread handle

Comment: oh, I thought you rediscovered the semaphore principle by yourself. Anyway, it should work all the same imho, so either solution is ok

Comment: The good thing about semaphores is that its self-contained. All the pertaining logic is included in a single object, so it's easy to manipulate. But sometimes for performance reasons people may prefer it differently (that's the logic behind unrolled loops for instance). Perhaps you thought it that way.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And in order to do that I'd need a semaphore that I can initialize with a negative value (if the implementation allows that, but I think all current implementations allows that by now) because what I want to do is exactly the reverse of the normal use of a semaphore :)

Comment: oh, cool, posix semaphores don't allow negative values `int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);`

Comment: true. I forgot that one. Actually I did something like your code last year when going through the standford CS107 videos in order to implement one of the assignements, and completely forgot about it. It used a condition and a mutex, but I made it a full fledged class.

Comment: cool! :) My point is that with semaphore you get an "OR" wait (I mean it unblocks the thread when at least 1 resource is free), otherwise I want an "AND" wait (I mean it unblocks when _ALL_ the resources are free) -- of course with negative value you can easily got the 2nd behavior ;)

Comment: Yes, it all depends on what the semaphore implementation let you do. On some platforms the semaphore value can be negative, but you have a (good) point with POSIX.